# Create hash in c# and validate in solidity

Tags: cryptography, hash, c#

I'm trying to build an app that will call a contract from javascript. I want the contract to validate that the parameters weren't tampered with. In order to do that, my plan was to figure out the parameters server-side, hash the combination of parameters, and sign the hash. I'd pass the hash and signature along to the contract for the contract to validate. The hash would prove the parameters haven't changed and the signature would prove that I generated the hash.

I'm currently trying to figure out the hashing part.

```
void Main()
{
    var bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");

    SHA256 hasher = SHA256Cng.Create();
    var hashed = hasher.ComputeHash(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", string.Empty));
}
```

gives me an output of `BA7816BF8F01CFEA414140DE5DAE2223B00361A396177A9CB410FF61F20015AD`

On the other side of the fence I have

```
pragma solidity 0.4.18;    

contract HashCheck {    
    function hash(bytes32 toHash) public returns(bytes32) {
        bytes32 hashed = sha256(toHash);
        return hashed;        
    }
}
```

which returns

```
truffle(development)> f.hash.call("abc")
'0x26426d7cb06a12643ccfe84107603083d835c37f000a12f734137a0c8df77f26'
```

I'm happy to try out keccak (sha3) hashing but I haven't figured out how to do that in C# yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function accepts `bytes32`, which is 32 bytes long. But in C#, you're only hashing 3 bytes. In C#, you need to *right* pad zeros to make the length 32.

Comment: Nice! That was it (except it's actually right-padded with nulls '\0' rather than zeroes).

`var abcBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc".PadRight(32, '\0'));`

Comment: `'\0'` is the character representation of the byte value `0`, so those are one and the same. (If you pad the string, you need to use characters. If you pad the bytes, you need bytes.)